# How can I assign a value to a read-only property?

Tags: javascript

I the following context I would like to have `USER_KEY = user_id` but all i get is an error that `USER_KEY is read-only`

```
const userKey = (user_id) => {
  USER_KEY = user_id;
}

export const USER_KEY = '';
export const onSignIn = () => AsyncStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, 'true');
export const onSignOut = () => AsyncStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY);
```

Comment: ...you can't change the value of constants. They're constant. Use a `let` or `var` declaration instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reassign a value with `const` declaration. You can use `let` to make a variable.

```
const userKey = (user_id) => {
  USER_KEY = user_id;
}

export let USER_KEY = '';
export const onSignIn = () => AsyncStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, 'true');
export const onSignOut = () => AsyncStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY);
```

Comment: `const` doesn't imply immutability, it simply means you can't reassign the variable